# Dynamic / Static items in radComboBox. (SQL Query error)

Tags: sql, telerik, drop-down-menu

I am using telerik's rad combo boxes (dropdowns) on my aspx page. there are 3 rad combo boxes and they are cascading dropdowns. the items in the final dropdown is dependent on the selection of the 2nd dropdown. 
Now, i had to insert a "select all" option in the final dropdown. this being a static value, i added it using "appenddatabounditems" property of the rad combo box, setting it to be true. I can now see the select all option, but the items in the dropdown list are repeated. I have used the distinct keyword in the query. Also, when i make another selection in the 2nd dropdown box, the values in the third dropdown are appended i.e they show "Select all" + items of the previously selected 2nd dropdown option + values of the currently selected dropdown selection.

Am i missing something in the query? or there is something wrong with the telerik controls? or the ajax manager?

PLease help.

Thanks,
ghanshyam.

Comment: You're going to have to post your SQL query if you want us to help fix it :)

Comment: SQL Query:
SELECT DISTINCT [Level3] FROM [DBTable] WHERE ([Level2] LIKE '%' + @Level2 + '%')
where @Level2 is the control parameter, which is the selected value of the dropdown of level2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the EnableLoadOnDemand="true" setting to perform the cascade?  The combo box does not clear the old items out automatically.  Two things you can do:

- Delete the old items OR
- Bind the entire list to the combo box and hide the invalid ones.  This has worked for us when the list is relatively small.

HTH.

Comment: I got the answer: I used the event "ondatabound" instead of "appenddatabouonditems" and it works fine now..! thank you all of you for the help.